# OpenCV Grayscale conversion giving unexpected Shape

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm programing a Neural network(CNN) where I'm providing images as input to the network.
I want to Ccovert the image into grayscale to reduce the depth of the image from 3 to 1.

I used the OpenCV Function for conversion as follows.

```
X = []
for name in cars:    
    img = cv2.imread(name,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    X.append(img)
for name in non_cars:    
    img = cv2.imread(name,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    X.append(img)
```

Have created X,which hold my data for training purpose.

each image is of 64 by 64 by 3
After Conversion into gray scale I should get 64 by 64 by 1.

Printing out Shape of my Array X

```
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
Output - X_train shape: (15984, 64, 64)
```

15984 are number of images.
I 'm expecting output to be  (15984, 64, 64,1)

My Neural Network gives me this Error :

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 64, 64) for Tensor 'image_input:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 3)'

Please guide me with Help.

Comment: The problem is with `X_train`, yet you do not show us how you created that. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load an image as grayscale as you are doing there, if you check the shape will be (64,64) and when you add and stack this images you will end up with (15984, 64, 64). The representation of the image using (64,64) can be viewed as a matrix of one channel 64 by 64 pixels. If you need to add the missing channel axis you can use:

```
img = img[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

Then you will end up with the shape like (64,64,1).

Note: You can do the same procedure on `X_train`. For more on that you can check [numpy.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).